# tools:overrideLibrary not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I'd like to use library `android.support.test.uiautomator.v18`in a build supporting Android back to level 11. My manifest begins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xxxdeletedxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        tools:overrideLibrary="com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18" />
```

and in build.gradle I have

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Running ./gradlew connectedCheck gives:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 18 declared in library [com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1] /Users/ewanbenfield/AndroidStudioProjects/TM/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support.test.uiautomator/uiautomator-v18/2.1.1/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18" to force usage
```

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a difference between the packages mentioned in your build.gradle and your AndroidManifest.

AndroidManifest should at least contain

```
<uses-sdk
    tools:overrideLibrary="com.android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>
```

and your build.gradle should contain

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
```

I recently had a similar problem where I forgot to put 'com.' in my AndroidManifest

Comment: Moreover: if the version given in SDK is com.mylib-1.1.1 then tools:overrideLibrary="com.mylib.1" can be written in manifest. So basically whatever version was written after dash will be taken into manifest consideration.

@Wirling is there a concept of using wildcard character like: tools:overrideLibrary="com.mylib.*" ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230777 ("build tools: processDebugManifest step fails or not depending on ordering of project dependencies")

In reported case reordering dependencies worked.